# Replace Null values with data from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm calculating a cumulative count (2 vlues from two tables). I managed to get the following result. Now I want to replace the NULL values like this :
If its the first row of the table then I need to insert the first not null value instead. For the rest of the rows, I need to insert the last non null value that comes before the current row.
Is ther a way to achieve this?

```
Date                    |  Count1 | Count2
2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 |  NULL   |  52
2016-01-02 00:00:00.000 |  NULL   |  54
2016-01-05 00:00:00.000 |  62     |  55
2016-01-08 00:00:00.000 |  NULL   |  56
2016-01-11 00:00:00.000 |  91     |  NULL
2016-01-12 00:00:00.000 |  92     |  59
```

Wanted Result :

```
Date                    |  Count1 | Count2
2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 |  62     |  52
2016-01-02 00:00:00.000 |  62     |  54
2016-01-05 00:00:00.000 |  62     |  55
2016-01-08 00:00:00.000 |  62     |  56
2016-01-11 00:00:00.000 |  91     |  56
2016-01-12 00:00:00.000 |  92     |  59
```

The query I used to generate this result :

```
declare @DateCountOpportunities table(d int primary key, c int, cr int)
insert into @DateCountOpportunities
select 
        datediff(d, 0, IsNull(CreationDate, StartDate)) as d,
        count(*) as OpportunitiesCount,
        0
        from [JobOpportunities]
        group by datediff(d, 0, IsNull(CreationDate, StartDate))

declare @rt int = 0
declare @anchor int

update  @DateCountOpportunities set
        @rt = cr = @rt + c,
        @anchor = d
option (maxdop 1)

declare @DateCountRestaurants table(d int primary key, c int, cr int)
insert into @DateCountRestaurants
select 
        datediff(d, 0, CreatedAt) as d,
        count(*) as RestaurantsCount,
        0
from [Restaurants]
group by datediff(d, 0, CreatedAt)

declare @rtRes int = 0
declare @anchorRs int

update  @DateCountRestaurants set
        @rtRes = cr = @rtRes + c,
        @anchorRs = d
option (maxdop 1)

Declare @ResultTable table(DateOpportunities DateTime, DateRestaurant DateTime, RestaurantsCount int, OpportunitiesCount int)
insert into @ResultTable

select isnull(DateOpportunities, DateRestaurants) DateOpportunities, isnull(DateRestaurants, DateOpportunities) DateRestaurant, RestaurantsCount, OpportunitiesCount from
(
    select
            dateadd(d, d, 0) as DateRestaurants,
            cr as RestaurantsCount
    from @DateCountRestaurants

) Rs

full outer join
(
    select
            dateadd(d, d, 0) as DateOpportunities,
            cr as OpportunitiesCount
    from @DateCountOpportunities  

)Opp
on Rs.DateRestaurants = Opp.DateOpportunities
order by DateOpportunities


select DateOpportunities as [Date], 
RestaurantsCount
, 
OpportunitiesCount from @ResultTable
```

Comment: This looks like the sort of thing that's better solved by modifying the original query that produces the result, rather than taking what's shown here as a given and piling on top of that. What's your base data and what's your current query?

Comment: If you are doing a cumulative count, I believe your answer lies in the query used to generate the output you displayed.  What you want to do is possible but could get complicated and is likely not necessary.  Can you post that query?

Comment: @JeroenMostert it's a complicated query, the problem is that I'm getting the cumulative count from two separate tables. I'll post the query if you want

Comment: Following the logic you have defined, The `count1` for the date `2016-01-08` shouldn't it be `91` ? and `Count2` for the date `2016-01-11` should be `59` ?

Comment: @M.Ali count2 for `2016-01-11` should be 56

Comment: Which SQL Server version ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean 2012

Comment: @HediNailyL SQL2012 has a dedicated feature for computing running totals: SUM(_) OVER(PARTITION BY _ ORDER BY _). Quirky update is a dangerous method. NB: I've used it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a rushed answer, but I hope it still helps. The query below will update all the records for one column only, so you might need to repeat the logic for the second column. There's probably also a way to alter this logic so that it handles both Count1 and Count2 within the same query (i.e. not requiring multiple UPDATE statements), but I don't have enough time right now to work through that solution.

I've tested the following with situations where the NULL is in the first row(s), center rows and at the last row with success:

```
CREATE TABLE #counting ( [Date] DATETIME, Count1 INT, Count2 INT )
INSERT INTO #counting
SELECT '2016-01-01', NULL, 52   UNION
SELECT '2016-01-02', NULL, 54   UNION
SELECT '2016-01-05', 62,   55   UNION
SELECT '2016-01-08', NULL, 56   UNION
SELECT '2016-01-11', 91,   NULL UNION
SELECT '2016-01-12', 92,   59   UNION
SELECT '2016-01-13', NULL, 56 


UPDATE
  #counting
SET
  Count1 = rangeValue
FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM
    (
      SELECT TOP 1
        firstDate,
        firstValue.[Date] AS lastDate,
        firstValue.Count1 AS rangeValue
      FROM
        #counting AS firstValue,
        ( SELECT MIN( [Date] ) AS firstDate FROM #counting WHERE Count1 IS NULL ) AS firstDate
      WHERE
        Count1 IS NOT NULL AND
        firstDate < firstValue.[Date]
      ORDER BY
        [Date]
    ) AS a
    UNION
    SELECT
      firstValueRecord.[Date] AS firstDate,
      lastNullRecord.[Date] AS lastDate,
      MAX( firstValueRecord.Count1 ) AS rangeValue
    FROM
      #counting AS firstValueRecord,
      #counting AS nonNullRecords,
      #counting AS lastNullRecord
    WHERE
      firstValueRecord.Count1 IS NOT NULL AND
      nonNullRecords.Count1 IS NOT NULL AND
      lastNullRecord.Count1 IS NULL AND
      lastNullRecord.[Date] > nonNullRecords.[Date] AND
      nonNullRecords.[Date] >= firstValueRecord.[Date]
    GROUP BY
      lastNullRecord.[Date],
      firstValueRecord.[Date]
    HAVING
      COUNT(DISTINCT nonNullRecords.[Date]) = 1
  ) AS a
WHERE
  Count1 IS NULL AND
  [Date] BETWEEN firstDate AND lastDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with SQL Server 2012 we can use `SUM()OVER(... ORDER BY ...)` to compute running totals. Example:

```
SELECT  *, SUM(t.Amount) OVER(ORDER BY t.ActionDate) AS RunningTotal
FROM (VALUES 
    ('2016-01-01 00:00:00.000', 62),
    ('2016-01-02 00:00:00.000', 0),
    ('2016-01-05 00:00:00.000', 0),
    ('2016-01-08 00:00:00.000', 0),
    ('2016-01-11 00:00:00.000', 29),
    ('2016-01-12 00:00:00.000', 0)
) t(ActionDate, Amount)
```

Results:

```
ActionDate              Amount      RunningTotal
----------------------- ----------- ------------
2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 62          62
2016-01-02 00:00:00.000 0           62
2016-01-05 00:00:00.000 0           62
2016-01-08 00:00:00.000 0           62
2016-01-11 00:00:00.000 29          91
2016-01-12 00:00:00.000 0           91
```

This means that initial T-SQL batch can be simplified thus:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(b.ActionDate, d.ActionDate) AS ActionDate,
    b.RunningTotal1,
    d.RunningTotal2
FROM 
(
    SELECT b.ActionDate, SUM(b.Amount) OVER(ORDER BY b.ActionDate) AS RunningTotal1
    FROM (
        SELECT  t.ActionDate, SUM(t.Amount) AS Amount
        FROM    dbo.FirstTable t
        GROUP BY t.ActionDate
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT  DISTINCT t.ActionDate, NULL AS Amount
        FROM    dbo.SeconTable t
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.FirstTable x WHERE x.ActionDate = t.ActionDate)
    ) a
) AS b
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT d.ActionDate, SUM(d.Amount) OVER(ORDER BY d.ActionDate) AS RunningTotal2
    FROM (
        SELECT  DISTINCT t.ActionDate, NULL AS Amount
        FROM    dbo.FirstTable t
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.SecondTable x WHERE x.ActionDate = t.ActionDate)
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT  t.ActionDate, SUM(t.Amount) AS Amount
        FROM    dbo.SeconTable t
        GROUP BY t.ActionDate
    ) c
) AS d
ON b.ActionDate = d.ActionDate
```

Comment: Note: I didn't tested this solution.